# INSERT INTO doesn't fill all rows

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I have a problem with my code, it is PayPal express Integration. I mean in its original state after some tweaking to match my database and so on it works, it fills rows with ex. payerID and so on.

I have in my database 2 tables - first is Products it has 5 Rows, like productID, Price, currency and so on, but I need 1 extra row - let's say we call it Credits. I manually added it to my database, filled Table Products with data.

Then I have another table called Orders- where I added Row called Credits too, than after successful payment+checkout matched Credits to chosen Product it should fill this Row Credits in Orders table. The problem that I have it that Order Table is filled with all data except that last Row -> Credits it's always showing NULL in the database.

This is part of my code:

```
    public function getAllProducts()
    {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");
        $stmt->bindParam("pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db=null;
        return $data;

    }

    public function getProduct($pid)
    {
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid=:pid");
        $stmt->bindParam("pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db=null;
        return $data;

    }
```

and this where I have a problem

```
    public function orders()
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['session_id'];
        $db = getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT P.product, P.price, P.product_img, P.currency, P.credits, O.created, O.oid  FROM orders O, products P WHERE O.id_fk=:id AND P.pid = O.pid_fk ORDER BY O.created DESC");
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->execute();
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db=null;
        return $data;

    }

    public function updateOrder($pid, $payerID, $paymentID, $token, $credits)
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['session_id'];
        if($this->pyamentCheck($paymentID) < 1 && $id > 0){
        $db = getDB();

        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (id_fk, pid_fk, payerID, paymentID, token, created, credits) VALUES (:id, :pid, :payerID, :paymentID, :token, :created, :credits)");
        $stmt->bindParam("paymentID", $paymentID, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("payerID", $payerID, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("token", $token, PDO::PARAM_STR) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("pid", $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->bindParam("id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $created = time();
        $stmt->bindParam("created", $created, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;
        $stmt->bindParam(":credits", $credits, PDO::PARAM_INT) ;

        $stmt->execute();
        $db=null;
        return true;

        }
        else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I can´t figure it out.

Comment: `$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products");` has no placeholder so that should now work either.

Comment: You should turn on exceptions and in put this in a try catch that will report the error.

Comment: did you try adding semicolon(:) before the name of the column in **bindParam** ?

Comment: yes i did, same result

Comment: Is this PDO or MySQLi? It is unlikely to be both. Would you delete one of these tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a frequent question so it deserves an answer, however obvious it may seem.

Once you have a **working** INSERT query and **one** of columns turns to be `NULL`, it means that the **source variable** contained `NULL`.

So the problem is neither with PDO, nor prepared statements, nor a database but simply with your source variable, `$credits`. You have to check your code related to this variable and make sure it does contain the desired value.

Comment: ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); does not show any errors, i tryied change in code name of Table and then it throw exception error, when i put right name of Table, it shows nothing i mean no error. Still in DB last row is NULL

Comment: @KamilWisniewski Maybe give `$credits` a default value in your function definition, `$credits = 0)` or debug where you call the function and what the variable is there.

Comment: Maybe i didnt wrote all info. I cannot put $Credit = 0 or 100 or 1000, becouse its paypal express checkout.  If User choose for ex. Product 1 it has in DB amount of Credits 100, if he choose Product 2 it has 200 and so on. So after he choose product he is redirected to paypal chceckout with session_id and pid-> product id. When he finish payment he should get those Credits with reference to this Session and pid. All Infos are filled into Order tables in DB except this additional one Credits. In Products table i filled Credits row with amounts. It still fill that last with NULL in Order table

Comment: @KamilWisniewski you should work further on your code. This is, actually what all programmers do. There is very little we can help you with, having no your code, no you database, no you paypal account. You have got an answer to the question why Credits column (it is called a column, not a row by the way) is null. Why your $credits variable is null is your job to find.